# How to define a function at android.defaultConfig level?

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, buildconfig

In my Android project in *build.gradle* use the following instructions to create **build config fields**.

```groovy
android {
    defaultConfig {
        if (project.hasProperty('serverOnePath')) {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_ONE_PATH",
                    "\"${serverOnePath}\""
        }
        if (project.hasProperty('serverTwoPath')) {
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_TWO_PATH",
                    "\"${serverTwoPath}\""
        }
    }
}
```

The properties therefore must be defined in *gradle.properties* as such:

```
serverOnePath=http://example1.com/path
serverTwoPath=http://example2.com/path
```

I would like to move the instructions into a function available at **`android.default` level**. Here is a **non-working** draft:

```groovy
def addBuildConfigFieldIfPropertyIsPresent(
    String propertyName, String buildConfigFieldName) {
    if (project.hasProperty(propertyName)) {
        android.defaultConfig.buildConfigField "String", buildConfigFieldName,
                "\"${propertyName}\""
    }
}
```

The tricky part is `${propertyName}`. Also it would be nice to actually put the declaration into the `defaultConfig` closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```groovy
android {
  defaultConfig {
    def configFieldFromProp = { propName, constName ->
      if (project.hasProperty(propName)) {
        buildConfigField "String", constName, "\"${project[propName]}\""
      }
    }

    configFieldFromProp "serverOnePath", "SERVER_ONE_PATH"
    configFieldFromProp "serverTwoPath", "SERVER_TWO_PATH"
  }
}
```

You can also add guava as a dependency to your build script and use `LOWER_CAMEL.to(UPPER_UNDERSCORE, propName)` to avoid typing the same thing twice.